# How to build a range slider using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I build a range slider from which I can get the range of two values, e.g., min and max? The scale widget seems not meet this requirement. I can only get one value from it and I don't want to use two scale to do this. 
Thanks

Comment: @joaquin do you know how to accept the answer? click "this answer is useful"? I am newbie to stackoverflow....thx

Comment: check out here: https://pypi.org/project/RangeSlider/

Answer (score 2):

You could create one by drawing the individual parts of the widget on a canvas. It's pretty easy to add bindings for dragging things around.

Comment: is there an easy way to not let the sliders overlap ? Or extend beyond the canvas boundary ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this ready-made tkinter widget: [RangeSlider](https://github.com/harshvinay752/RangeSlider)

Another RangeSlider for customtkinter if you are interested: [CTkRangeSlider](https://github.com/Akascape/CTkRangeSlider)

[image: My screenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31880450)